# Equations on printf using else if

Tags: c, if-statement, equation

Make and run a program that will compute the total cost charges of a telephone call rendered from a particular network using the given table. The user will input call destination code (1 to 5), time code (1=off-peak, 2=peak), and the duration of call.

```
  Off-peak Hours                Rate/min
  1 Calls to the same network     P 8
  2 Call to other network         P 8
  3 Call to a landline            P 8
  4 National direct dial          P 11
  5 International direct dial     P 20

  Peak hours                     Rate/min
  1 Calls to the same network     P 3
  2 Call to other network         P 4
  3 Call to a landline            P 4
  4 National direct dial          P 7
  5 International direct dial     P 20
```

*the program runs but all conditions follow eq1 even if i told it to print eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5 or eq6... meaning every number i input just multiply the duc by 8.

---------------------------------------...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
int dc, tc, duc, eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6;

printf("Time Code:");
scanf("%d", &tc);
printf("Destination Code:");
scanf("%d", &dc);
printf("Duration Call:");
scanf("%d", &duc);

eq1=duc*8;
eq2=duc*11;
eq3=duc*3;
eq4=duc*4;
eq5=duc*7;
eq6=duc*20;

{
if((tc=1) && (dc=1))
printf("%d", eq1);
else if((tc=1) && (dc=2))
printf("%d", eq1);
else if((tc=1) && (dc=3))
printf("%d", eq1);
else if((tc=1) && (dc=4))
printf("%d", eq2);
else if((tc=1) && (dc=5))
printf("%d", eq6);
else if((tc=2) && (dc=1))
printf("%d", eq3);
else if((tc=2) && (dc=2))
printf("%d", eq4);
else if((tc=2) && (dc=3))
printf("%d", eq4);
else if((tc=2) && (dc=4))
printf("%d", eq5);
else if((tc=2) && (dc=5))
printf("%d", eq6);
}

getch();
}
```

Comment: `=` is not quite the same as `==`.

Comment: Moreover, you'd probably want to refer to `switch-case` for your given example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator
`==` is the equality operator
`if(tc=1)` is the same as `if(1)`, so will always be true regardless of the `tc` value (even if it is not equal to 1).

Make it your habbit to speak the `=` operator as **assigned to variable** (like tc gets assiged the value of 1). While the `==` could be read as **equals to**, or **equal equal**. It will also help when you explain code to someone else.

Comment: I will this to my classmates as well :)

Answer (score 4):

```
if((tc=1) && (dc=1))
```

All the conditions in the `if` and `else if` uses the assignment operator `=`, while you should use `==` to test equality.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: No. Why do you think that would help?

Comment: @user2357112 No else are not needed here... although bug is due to misspell `==`, Am I not correct?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: It happens to be the case that the `else`s aren't necessary. That doesn't explain why you think it would help.

Comment: @user2357112 I first posted my comment to question, But because it was just a suggestion I deleted old comment and commented to the correct answer...

Comment: oh my, ive' been trying to configure it since morning and those == were my only mistake. its been fixed now, thank you very much :)

Comment: @user3259739 Now you may like to know about [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan those yoda conditions, explained it well :) thank you.